# Why states are still undefined after being passed to props via mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-state, mapstatetoprops

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    counter: state.counter,
    isLogged: state.isLogged
  }
}
```

This is how I passed the states. However, error comes saying counter and isLogged is undefined. Why ?

Comment: You need to share more code than this. No one can tell you anything just by looking at a function. Have you setup your reducer? Do they have a default state? Is your data flowing through your reducers? Do you get data in your hook? What happens when you console log state?

Answer (score 0):

The `state` will contain an object with all your reducers so check if `counter` and `isLogged` are the names of your reducers. I would suggest removing the `state.counter` and the `state.isLogged` on the return and checking what the `console.log(state)` prints